# Не получается запустить npm через wmic

Tags: windows, npm, bat

Если в bat-файл помещаю команду запуска `node`

```
wmic process call create "npm run go","%~dp0."
```

то всё работает:

```
D:\Temp\Supertemp\wmic npm>wmic process call create "node go","D:\Temp\Supertemp\wmic npm\."
Идет выполнение (Win32_Process)->Create()
Метод успешно вызван.
Параметры вывода:
instance of __PARAMETERS
{
        ProcessId = 13292;
        ReturnValue = 0;
};
```

Но стоит заменить её на `npm`

```
wmic process call create "npm run go","%~dp0."
```

и происходит ошибка 9, которая [согласно msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/aa389388(v=vs.85).aspx) означает, что путь не найден:

```
D:\Temp\Supertemp\wmic npm>wmic process call create "npm run go","D:\Temp\Supertemp\wmic npm\."
Идет выполнение (Win32_Process)->Create()
Метод успешно вызван.
Параметры вывода:
instance of __PARAMETERS
{
        ReturnValue = 9;
};
```

Файл `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "wmic-npm-test",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "go": "node go"
  }
}
```

Файл `go.js`:

```
setInterval(function () {
  console.log(require('process').cwd());
}, 1000);
```

Просто из консоли всё работает:

```
D:\Temp\Supertemp\wmic npm>npm run go

> wmic-npm-test@0.0.0 go D:\Temp\Supertemp\wmic npm
> node go

D:\Temp\Supertemp\wmic npm
D:\Temp\Supertemp\wmic npm
```

Запуск именно через `wmic` [нужен для получения id запускаемого процесса](//stackoverflow.com/q/46182585/4928642).

PS: [Этот вопрос на английском.](//stackoverflow.com/q/46194909/4928642)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Существуют одновременно `npm.cmd` и файл `npm` для `sh`:

```
D:\Temp\Supertemp\wmic npm>where npm
C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm
C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd
```

Чтобы выполнить команду `npm`, надо явно указать, что нужен cmd-файл:

```
wmic process call create "npm.cmd run go","%~dp0."
```